# 'bridged' wifi for qemu kvm (ebtables / parprouted / etc)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint, virtual-machine, kvm

I'm trying to set up a virtual machine with a Linux Mint 18.3 host and Win10 x64 guest.

I need this VM accessible from my network. Unfortunately, snaking an Ethernet cable into my room is not an option, and my wifi's chipset (BCM4360) does not support WDS (`sudo iw dev wlp6s0 set 4addr on` gives an error). So I can't create a *real* bridge.

I've spent the past 3 days trying a variety of solutions, attempting to get this to work. The best solution I've found so far puts the VM behind a NAT, but at least the VM is able to ping other machines on the network and I get virtio performance gains. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207907

Unfortunately, this makes my VM invisible to the rest of the network.

I've tried using this: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC

But far as I am able to tell, `ebtables` hasn't done anything.

I also tried using `parprouted` as described here:
https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp

However it doesn't seem to work even though the description says

> "Reboot, and hosts connected to the bridge's ethernet should acquire a
>   DHCP address and have full IP connectivity!"

So maybe I just don't have this hooked up right in my VM config?

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1) Does your BCM4360 support two stations at once? (Look at `valid interface combinations` in `iw phy`). If yes, make a second station and pass the network interface through to the VM.

2) If you can control your router (via OpenWRT etc.), try a tunnel for a second network interface. You'll need to add the tunnel endpoint to the LAN/WLAN client bridge on the router.

3) If none of these work, and as you don't have four-address-mode, keep in mind that in this case the wifi interface will only work *with a single MAC address*. Which means you *either* connect the host to the network, *or* the VM guest, but not both.

If you can live with the host not being visible on the network, have a look at [wlan_kabel](https://github.com/escitalopram/wlan_kabel). It uses a raw socket to basically steal all packets from the host, and pass it on to some other interface.

I tried proxy arp once, but never got it working properly.

4) If you really need both the host and the VM on the network, I'd think buying a cheap WLAN dongle would be simplest option.